# Stacked PR rebase / amend workflow

Tags: git

I have the following workflow for doing stacked pull requests in git (I like to do lots of small, dependent PRs):

```
* Start your feature_b from feature_a, i.e.:
git checkout feature_a
git checkout -b feature_b
* Whenever feature_a changes while it is waiting to get merged into master, you rebase feature_b on it:
... commit something onto feature_a ...
git checkout feature_b
git rebase feature_a
* Finally, as soon as feature_a has been merged into master, you simply get the new master and rebase feature_a onto it a last time:
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout feature_b
git rebase --onto master feature_a feature_b
```

This works for a few dependencies, but after I get to around `feature_c` or d, I end up have to rebase a bunch of times if I want to change something in the `feature_a` branch. Ideally I want a “amend this commit and rebase all dependent commits onto it” command to run when I edit a given PR, as well as a "rebase all but the first x commits onto master" command when I merge one or more of the initial PRs and still have the rest in review.

When I used mercurial, I used `hg amend --rebase` (https://bitbucket.org/facebook/hg-experimental) to do this for me. Curious if there’s an equivalent in git or a script I could write to implement the same functionality?

[rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) looks like it could be a good tool to use here, in conjunction with other things to automate the dependent rebase process itself.

Comment: you should try merge instead of rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update as of Nov 2022: git 2.38 released `git rebase --update-refs` which essentially does what I'm asking for. Check out the [github blog](https://github.blog/2022-10-03-highlights-from-git-2-38/) for more info and a nice example.

Answer (score 1):

I've never found a good technical solution to this. That you get several layers deep might indicate your review and merge process is too slow. Or that your branches are too fine. Or too interdependent. Or all of that.

## Review process too slow

Obviously we all want our PRs reviewed and merged as fast as possible. Some places do this faster than others. It might be a slow CI process. It might be that developers don't prioritize reviewing. It might be that PRs are too complex. I can't say how to fix this in your project, only that it will exacerbate other problems.

## Branches are too fine and too interdependent

You're stacking branches presumably because feature A needs feature B which needs feature C and so on. If you're doing this habitually the question to ask is why your work is so habitually interdependent? Why can't features A, B, and C be developed independently? Branch dependencies are a sometimes food.

It could be because the code has too many interdependencies and needs to be refactored. It could be that the tasks are too interdependent and need to be rethought. It could be that the branches are too large and contain too much necessary changes. Again, I can't say for your shop, but I'd suggest you think about it.

## Do you need to merge each feature right now?

Unless you absolutely need feature A merged right now and it can't wait for dependent features B and C to be done, maybe just do them as one branch. If you'd like feedback as you work, you can push the branch and ask for feedback on what you've done so far.